# What is the replacement for sp_MSforeachtable procedure

Tags: sql-server, sp-msforeachtable

What is the replacement solution from Microsoft for the (to be deprecated) procedure `sp_MSforeachtable` on SQL Server newer versions?

Comment: I don't think there is one other than resorting to a CLR procedure or a cursor.